# wrap xml column values into outer for xml path query

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to wrap the xml from a column into an out for xml path query without
the column name as an element.

```
declare @tab table (col xml)
insert @tab
select '<element/>'

select  'val' AS "@att" , col
from  @tab
for xml path ('ROOT')
```

This gives

```
<ROOT att="val">
  <col>
    <element />
  </col>
</ROOT>
```

but i want

```
<ROOT att="val">
    <element />
</ROOT>
```

All help most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little cleaner method.

```
SELECT
    'val' AS [@att], 
    [col] AS [*]
FROM
    @tab
FOR XML PATH ('ROOT');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select
  'val' AS "@att",
  (select col)
from  @tab
for xml path ('ROOT')
```

Comment: perfect, thanks  iwas trying this select  'val' AS "@att" , CAST(col AS XML)
from  @tab
for xml PATH ('ROOT') but your solution is better.